# How to remove "None" from output of function related question

Tags: python

```
    def function1():
    print("Aww im sorry to hear")
    
def function2():
    print("Thats fantastic")    
    
    
def function3():
    print("Invalid response")    
    

ansr = input(print("Did you have a good day at school? Answer 'Y' or 'N'!!"))

if ansr == "Y":
    function2()
elif ansr == "N":
    function1()
else:
    function3()
```

Output

```
    Did you have a good day at school? Answer 'Y' or 'N'!!
None
```

Is there any reason "none" is being returned?? and if so how would i adjust my code to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't `print` inside `input`. The prompt message is automatic.

```
ansr = input("Did you have a good day at school? Answer 'Y' or 'N'!!")
```

---

`print` returns `None` here a similar example

```
print(print('Hallo'))
```

Output

```
Hallo
None
```